# __asm nop for breakpoints with MinGW compiler?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, mingw, inline-assembly

I want to create stop points for debugger by `__asm nop` command (next step to create `#define __asm nop stop`) and simple use it. But it doesn't works well as it works in Visual Studio with MSVS, I cant change compiler in this project and I have to use MinGW.

I dont know right syntax for this problem in MinGW, what is the best way to implement this in MinGW/Qt?

Comment: MinGW uses the gcc compiler, and gcc's inline assembly features are [well documented in its manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C).  The syntax looks like `asm("nop");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `__asm__("nop");` or `asm("nop");` (suggested solution by [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) )